# Creating buffers that automatically update when new feature added using ArcGIS Online

Tags: point, arcgis-online, buffer, arcgis-online-webmap

Is it possible to create a new feature in ArcGIS Online and the buffer automatically update?

I need to create a point in ArcGIS Online and produce the point together with its buffer.